# Get column objects for model definition via classmethod

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

How do I get all column names for an existing model in SQLAlchemy that is defined using a Base class with some columns defined there already? I am looking for a `@classmethod`, not for an instance method.

The model is not yet bound to a table, I have no `__table__` attribute of the model definition yet.

I can loop through the **dict** and look at the types but surely there is a better way? I cannot use `inspect`, I get the error: 'No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.decl_api.DeclarativeMeta'>'